# Need some clarifications regarding a computational example in ring theory provided in the book Topics in Algebra by IN Herstein in Section-3.9

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was reading about polynomial rings from the book "Topics in Algebra" by IN Herstein.

Particularly, I was going through a computation given on Pg-157, Section-3.9. I am going to quote the portion that I am talking about. Here it is:

Let $F$ be the field of rational numbers and consider the polynomial
$p(x) = x^3 - 2$ in $F[x].$ As is easily verified, it is irreducible over $F,$ whence
$F[x]/(x^3 - 2)$ is a field. What do its elements look like? Let $A = (x^3 - 2),$
the ideal in $F[x]$ generated by $x^3 - 2.$
Any element in $F[x]/(x^3 - 2)$ is a coset of the form $f(x) +A$ of the
ideal $A$ with $f(x)$ in $F[x].$ Now, given any polynomial $f(x)\in F[x],$ by
the division algorithm, $f(x) = t (x) (x^3 - 2) + r(x),$ where $r(x) = 0$ or
$\deg r(x) < \deg (x^3 - 2) = 3.$ Thus $r(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2$ where $a_0 , a_1, 
a_2$ are in $F;$ consequently $f(x) + A = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + t (x) (x^3 - 2) + A = a_0 + a_1x + a_2 x_2 +A$ since $t(x)(x^3 - 2)$ is in $A,$ hence by the addition and multiplication in $F[x]/(x^3 - 2),$ is $ f (x) + A = (a_0 + A) + 
a_1 (x +A) + a_2 (x + A)^2.$ If we put $t = x +A,$ then every element in
$F[x]/(x^3 - 2)$ is of the form $a_0 + a_1t + a_2 t^2$ with $a_0 , a_1, a_2$ in $F.$ What about $t?$

Since $t^3 - 2 = (x + A)^3 - 2 = x^3 - 2 + A = A = 0$ (since $A$ is
the zero element of $F[x]/(x^3 - 2)$) we see that $t^3 = 2.$

Also, if $a_0 + a_1t + a_2t^2 = b_0 + b_1t + b_2 t^2,$ then $$(a_0 - b_0) + (a_1 - b_1 )t +(a_2 - b_2 )t^2=0,$$ whence $$(a_0 - b_0 ) + (a_1 - b_1 )x + (a_2 - b_2 )x^2$$ is in  $A = (x^3 - 2).$Also, if $a_0 + a_1t + a_2t^2 = b_0 + b_1t + b_2 t^2,$ then $$(a_0 - b_0) + (a_1 - b_1 )t +(a_2 - b_2 )t^2=0,$$ whence $$(a_0 - b_0 ) + (a_1 - b_1 )x + (a_2 - b_2 )x^2$$ is in  $A = (x^3 - 2).$ How can this be, since every element in $A$ has degree at least $3$? Only if $a_0 - b_0 + (a_1 - b_1 )x + (a_2 - b_2 )x^2 = 0,$ that is, only if $a_0 = b_0, a_1 = b_1, a_2 = b_2.$ Thus every element in $F[x]/(x^3 - 2)$ has
a unique representation as $a_0 + a_1t + a_2t^2$ where $a_0 , a_1 , a_2 \in F.$

It would be instructive to see this directly;
all that it entails is proving that if $a_0 + a_1 t + a_2 t^2 \neq 0$ then it has an inverse of the form $\alpha+\beta t+\gamma t^2.$ Hence we must solve for $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ in the relation $(a_0 + a_1t + a_2 t^
2 )(\alpha + \beta t + \gamma t^2 ) = 1,$ where not all of $a_0,a_1 , a2$
are $ 0.$ Multiplying the relation out and using $t^3 = 2$ we obtain
$(a_0\alpha  + 2a_2\beta+ 2a_1\gamma)+ (a_1\alpha + a_0\beta+ 2a_2\gamma)t + (a_2\alpha + a_1\beta+ a_0\gamma)t^2 = 1.$

---

It is written that,

> Since $t^3 - 2 = (x + A)^3 - 2 = x^3 - 2 + A = A = 0$ (since $A$ is
> the zero element of $F[x]/(x^3 - 2)$) we see that $t^3 = 2.$

I don't get this, how do they write $t^3=2$ ? Firstly, they denote $A$ by $0$ and $0$ is just a symbol and at most we can write, $t^3=A+2=0+2.$ But how can they claim, $A+2=0+2=2$ ? We note that, $0+2=A+2\in F[x]/(x^3-2)=F[x]/A$ but the claim made in the portion suggests that, $2\in F[x]/(x^3-2)$ and this last relation is absurd. So, I interpret $t^3=A+2.$

With this interpretation of $t^3$ I had a different issue. In the part where they write,

> Hence we must solve for $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ in the relation $(a_0 + a_1t + a_2 t^
> 2 )(\alpha + \beta t + \gamma t^2 ) = 1,$ where not all of $a_0,a_1 , a_2$
> are $ 0.$

I think by the symbol $1$ they are referring to the element $1+A.$

So we precisely have, $(a_0 + a_1t + a_2 t^
2 )(\alpha + \beta t + \gamma t^2 )  = 1+A.$

They go on by saying,

> Multiplying the relation out and using $t^3 = 2$ we obtain
> $(a_0\alpha  + 2a_2\beta+ 2a_1\gamma)+ (a_1\alpha + a_0\beta+ 2a_2\gamma)t + (a_2\alpha + a_1\beta+ a_0\gamma)t^2 = 1.$

It seems to me that they are indeed substituting, $t^3=2$ in the equality, $(a_0 + a_1t + a_2 t^
2 )(\alpha + \beta t + \gamma t^2 ) = 1,$ after expanding. This seems strange, for $t=x+A$ is a coset and $t^3=2$ is weird and makes no sense to me. We must also observe that $2\notin F[x]/A$ instead, $2\in F$ and $t^3\in F[x]/A.$ What are they substituting $t=2$ in this equality just like that?

Any clarification regarding this issue will be greatly appreciated.

I tried to do the computation in a more "normal" way:
$$(a_0 + a_1t + a_2 t^
2 )(\alpha + \beta t + \gamma t^2 ) = 1+A\implies a_0\alpha+(a_0\beta+a_1\gamma)t+(a_0\gamma +a_1\beta+a_2\alpha)t^2+(a_1\gamma+a_2\beta)t^3+a_2\gamma t^4=1+A\implies a_0\alpha+(a_0\beta+a_1\gamma)(2+A)+(a_0\gamma +a_1\beta+a_2\alpha)(4+A)+(a_1\gamma+a_2\beta)(8+A)+a_2\gamma (16+A)=1+A\implies a_0\alpha+(2a_0\beta+2a_1\gamma)+(4a_0\gamma +4a_1\beta+4a_2\alpha)+(8a_1\gamma+8a_2\beta)+16a_2\gamma +A=1+A\implies a_0\alpha +2a_2\beta+2a_1\gamma+(a_1\alpha+a_0\beta+2a_2\gamma)t+(a_2\alpha+a_1\beta+a_0\gamma)t^2+6a_2\beta+6a_1\gamma+12a_2\gamma=1+A.$$

But I don't get why the term, $6a_2\beta +6a_1\gamma+12a_2\gamma$ is not prsent in the expression, $(a_0\alpha  + 2a_2\beta+ 2a_1\gamma)+ (a_1\alpha + a_0\beta+ 2a_2\gamma)t + (a_2\alpha + a_1\beta+ a_0\gamma)t^2 = 1$ in the book.

Comment: It is a shorthand for your interpretation that is meaningful because the quotient ring by an ideal is well-defined: $(r + A) + (s + A) = (r + s) + A$, $(r + A)(s + A) = rs + A$. Specifying explicitly that these are cosets modulo $A$ would mostly be useful if you do computations in both rings simultaneously (to prevent the reader from confusing them), but many would prever less verbose notation like $\overline{2}$.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist But why is it justified to substitute $t^3=2$ in the equality $$(a_0 + a_1t + a_2 t^
2 )(\alpha + \beta t + \gamma t^2 ) = 1,$$ just like that?

Comment: You can use $t^3 = 2 + A$ instead and will get the same result using formulae from my comment. The "formally correct" version of this equation would look like $(a_0+A+(a_1+A)t+(a_2+A)t^2)(\alpha+A+(\beta+A)t+(\gamma+A)t^2)=1+A$ — this is just visual clutter.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist When I try to simplify $$(a_0+A+(a_1+A)t+(a_2+A)t^2)(\alpha+A+(\beta+A)t+(\gamma+A)t^2)=1+A$$ I end up, with $$(a_0\alpha + 2a_2\beta+ 2a_1\gamma)+ (a_1\alpha + a_0\beta+ 2a_2\gamma)t + (a_2\alpha + a_1\beta+ a_0\gamma+3a_2\gamma)t^2 = 1+A$$. However, I really don't get why the term $3a_2\gamma$ is missing in $$(a_0\alpha  + 2a_2\beta+ 2a_1\gamma)+ (a_1\alpha + a_0\beta+ 2a_2\gamma)t + (a_2\alpha + a_1\beta+ a_0\gamma)t^2 = 1$$ as given in the book?

Comment: How do you get $3a_2 \gamma t^2?$ There are no terms of fifth degree in the initial expansion (before using the reduction $t^3 \to 2$).

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist I have shown the calculations in the OP. Mind taking a look at it? I don't get where's the mistake.

Comment: The best is to view the multiplication and addition in the quotient $F[x] / A$ as just these operations modulo the polynomial $x^3-2$. Finding inverse of an elements works best if we use extended Euclidean algorithm rather than the brute force approach.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh But can you explain why are we getting those extra terms?

Comment: We have to put $t^3=2$ and not $t=2$. That's the issue with your calculation.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh No, I am substituting, $t=2+A$.

Comment: But you can't substitute $t$ ie $x+A$ as $2+A$. What is guaranteed is $t^3=(x+A)^3=2+A$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks a ton! I get where I made the mistake.